How to prevent power fluctuations on strong Electromagnetic Lock (2A)?
I'm learning how to control strong Electromagnet Lock using ESP32 microcontroller, but I'm having problems with board freezing at the end of relay activation. So the Lock works, but then the board freezes. Looks like some power spike (?) problem or is it Step-Down Converter poor quality (MP1584)?
So how can I protect the circuit better or separate power better way?


Do you have 'scope traces of the power fluctuation? Can you elaborate on why the diode is connected as a rectifying diode rather than in the usual flyback diode configuration if the concern is relay turn-off?

the voltage difference between +12 V and -12 V is 24 V ... did you mean to label the power supply as +12 V and GND?

@jsotola yes, this is 12V power supply, mb

@nanofarad I don't have the equipment nor knowledge to measure the power; as for diode, I'm experimenting with different configurations and diodes and this is what I currently ended up with. So do I need to connect my diode in parallel?

is the electromagnet designed for DC or AC?

@jsotola this is 12V DC Electromagnet

Short Answer
Assuming DC input supply and DC electromagnet, the diode serves no purpose as shown.
It should instead be connected with the anode to the relay-electromagnet connection, and the cathode connected to +12V (along with the electromagnet). This configuration is known as anti-parallel because it is in parallel with the coil, but with the opposite polarity.

The purpose of an anti-parallel diode is to provide a conduction path the inductive kickback when the coil is switched off to prevent damage or misbehaviour in the rest of the circuit.
Make sure the diode has a suitably rated forward current. It should be rated for continuous current of more than the current rating of the electromagnet. The RL207 is only rated for 2A continuous which is probably insufficient.

The why
The coil is heavily inductive, with the voltage across the inductive component given nominally by:
$$V = L\frac{di}{dt}$$
Initially you turn the relay on which applies a voltage across it, which causes the current to ramp up as voltage is proportional to rate of change of current.
You then switch the relay off, which in an ideal world (this is not ideal so bare with) require a rate of change of current of negative infinity - dropping the current to zero in no time at all. This would produce a voltage across the coil terminals of negative infinite volts.
In reality nothing is ideal, so there will be no infinity, but there will still be a very large negative spike in voltage of possibly several kilovolts. What affect this has on the rest of the circuit is difficult to predict, but damaging power supplies, and causing transients that affect digital circuits are quite common.
By placing a diode anti-parallel - i.e. with opposite polarity to the coil - then when the coil is on, the diode does nothing (reverse biased). But when turned off, the diode provides a current path for the coil. Remember that the current starts to drop when turned off, so the voltage across it goes negative, which means the diode is now forward biased and can conduct.
Because current can flow through the diode, it can continue to flow through the coil. Instead of getting a large voltage spike, the voltage across the coil is limited to the forward voltage drop of the diode. Instead of instantly dropping to zero, current continues flowing with rate of decay \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ limited to be proportional to the diode voltage drop until it reaches zero and the diode turns off.
The limited rate of decay means the electromagnet will continue to be energised for a period of time after the relay is turned off as the current decays. If you want to adjust this decay time, you can place a resistor or zener diode in series with the anti-parallel diode. This increases the voltage across the coil while turning off which in turn allows a faster rate of change.

For example placing an 11V Zener diode with appropriate power rating in series anti-parallel diode would initially result in approximately -12V across the coil when switching off rather than -1V (diode forward voltage), so will make the switch off time 12x faster, whilst continuing to limit the voltage to a sensible level.

It's a 2A lock,  assuming the current is constrained by the lock resistance then the worst  case is 1A average current through the diode.  so even a 1A diode like  1N400x would work and a 2A diode has 50% headroom
